# VSCode GitExtension determines that two projects are related when copying a file

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-extensions

I'm using VS Code.

When I copied file a from project A to project B, the Git extension in project B now shows project A.
It disappeared when I unchecked it with `ViewAndSort> Repositories`, but it is still displayed as a push destination option when pushing.

Since Project A is irrelevant, I would like to hide it completely and remove it from the push destination options. How can I do it?

Also, I would like to turn off the function that determines that two projects are related when copying a file in the first place. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just close editor and reopen it.